# Returns nothing when passing value back from Helper Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am passing a list of objects from the Controller to a function in a Helper Class which is to return a dictionary back. However, the return value I am getting is always nothing. My list of objects works fine and the values are present so the error is in the helper class.

This is my Controller:

```html
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Form(List<Student> s)
        {
        var c = new HelperClass();
        var result = c.helpermethod(s);
        ViewBag.Result = s.Count; // RETURNS CORRECT LENGTH
        ViewBag.Value = result.Count; // ALWAYS RETURN ZERO
        return View("Index");
        }
```

Method in my Helper Class :

```html
public Dictionary<Person,int> helpermethod(List<Student> s)
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<string, int>();
  
           
            List<string> k = new List<string>();
            List<int> v = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
            {
                var d = s[i];
                if (k.Contains(d.Name)){ 
                    int index = k.FindIndex(a => a == d.Name);
                    v[index]+= d.Age;
                }
                else {
                    k.Append(d.Name);  
                    v.Append(d.Age);
                }
       
            }
            // Create Dictionary
            for (int i = 0; i < k.Count; i++)
            {
                var p= new Person(k[i]) ;
                result.Add(Person, v[i]);
            }
         return result;
        }
```

Dictionary is Person Object:

```html
public class Person
    {
        public string p { get; set; }

        // Intializing class
        public Person(string x)
        {
            p = x;
        }
    }
```

Key of Dictionary is a Student Object:

This is my model:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MVCModel.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to debug your code.

Comment: Please give variables usefull names! You assume in the result a Dict with `<string, int>`, but you are trying to add a Model `<Person, int>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is in this snippet:

```cs
else {
    k.Append(d.Name);  
    v.Append(d.Age);
}
```

`.Append()` is a LINQ extension method which **does not modify** the original collection, it simply returns a new `IEnumerable` with the added element at the end. That means that `k` and `v` stay empty, and the last for-cycle in `helpermethod` never runs. Since `k` and `v` are `List`, use `.Add()` instead. Or even better, use [ToDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-6.0).

Other than that, I see a few more issues in your code:

```
var result = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

should be `Dictionary<Person, int>`, it shouldn't even compile as it is, since it does not match the return type of `helpermethod`.

```
result.Add(Person, v[i]);
```

should be `result.Add(p, v[i]);`, `Person` is a type.

Answer (score 0):

**First off, where is the `Person` variable declared in your code?**

```
...
            // Create Dictionary
            for (int i = 0; i < k.Count; i++)
            {
                var p= new Person(k[i]) ;
                result.Add(Person, v[i]); // <-- What is Person here?? Did you mean p?
            }
```

Secondly, why not just use:

```
var res = s.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Age);
```

No need to reinvent the wheel.

Furthermore, why not expand the `Person` class to hold the age and return a `List<Person>` instead of a `Dictionary<string, int>`?

Like this:

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Age { get; set; }

        // Intializing class
        public Person(string name, int age)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
        }
    }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
...
var persons = s.Select(student => new Person(student.Name, student.Age);

ViewBag.Value = persons.Count();
```

it's much easier to understand and is less error-prone.